# Copy the selected row into defined number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

What change do i need to do in the below code so that the entire row is copied into a defined number of rows and not just the first column?

```
Sub InsertSessions()
Dim Rng As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim rRange As Range

Set rRange = Selection

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

Rng = InputBox("Enter number of sessions:.")
For k = 1 To Rng
Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
           CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Call rRange.Copy(Range(Cells(rRange.Row - 1, rRange.Column), Cells(rRange.Row - 1, rRange.Column)))


Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work with no loop needed:

```
Option Explicit
Sub InsertSessions()

    Dim rRange As Range
    Set rRange = Selection.EntireRow

    Dim Rng As Long
    Rng = InputBox("Enter number of sessions:.") * rRange.Rows.Count

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim StartRng As Range
        Set StartRng = .Cells(rRange.Cells(rRange.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1), 1)

        StartRng.Resize(Rng).Insert xlDown
        rRange.Copy .Range(.Cells(StartRng, 1), .Cells(StartRng.Offset(Rng - 1), 1))
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @JayWanjari glad I could help. Please consider marking the answer as correct so the question can be closed.

Comment: Can you also make changes in your above code to copy the first two rows and then paste them into defined number of rows subsequently.

Comment: For ex:The range should include row 1 and 2...Then if i enter the number of sessions as 1 then row1 should get copied in row 3 and row 2 should get copied in row 4 and so on.

Comment: @JayWanjari yes, but the code would change. Try my edit, it shoudl work with more than one row.

Comment: this edit isn't working.When i select both the rows and run the program #NA value appears.Also when i select just one row and run the program the first row replaces the second row.

Comment: @JayWanjari this took a little bit more of tweaking, but there you go. Tested and working.